# Annotation @Component Scan Not Working but Component Scan in xml is working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use the [ComponentScan annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckwZU.png).
It does not seem to be working even thought it does if I use it in the `.xml`file.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What problems do you have? What behaviour do you expect and what behaviour do you get?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put those annotations on a "Configuration Class" not at the Main class.

Answer (score 0):

try static ApplicationContext.
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

```
@Bean
public ExampleBean exampleBean() {
    return new ExampleBean();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    applicationContext = 
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringComponentScanApp.class);
```

Check this example.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning